# Should requirejs be included in the main built file when using the requirejs bundles option

Tags: requirejs, r.js

I'm running into an issue when using the require bundles option.  If the main built file has requirejs inside of it everything works fine until I try to load a file from a different bundle.  The bundled file is retrieved but then throws an "define is undefined" error.  The only way I have been able to get the bundle to load is to make sure requirejs is not in the main-built file or the pm.js and then to load requirejs with a script tag and use the data-main attribute, but this doesn't seem right.

So something like this initially works when requirejs is included in main-built.js (site loads fine), but I get the "define is undefined" error when pm.js bundle loads

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/main-built.js"></script>

requirejs.config({
    bundles: {
        'pm': ['pm/dashboard', 'text!pm/dashboard.html']
    }
});
```

This is how I ended up getting it to work, but doesn't seem right.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/require.js" data-main="dist/main-debug")"></script>
```

This durandal task creates the main-built file

```html
        durandal: {
            main: {
                src: ["app/**/*.*", "scripts/durandal/**/*.*", "!app/mockup/**/*.*", "!app/performancemanagement/**/*.*"],
                options: {
                    //name: "scripts/require",
                    name: "",
                    baseUrl: requireConfig.baseUrl,
                    paths: mixIn({}, requireConfig.paths, { "require": "scripts/require.js" }),
                    exclude: ["jquery", "knockout", "toastr", "moment", "underscore", "amplify"],
                    optimize: "none",
                    out: "dist/main-debug.js"
                }
            },
        },
```

This task builds the pm.js bundle

```html
requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    include: generateFileList("app/pm", "**/*.*", false, false),
                    //exclude: ["jquery", "knockout", "toastr", "moment", "underscore", "amplify", "preferenceconstants", "constants", "config", "utility/koutilities", "scripts/logger", "base/viewmodel"]
     // .concat(generateFileList("scripts/durandal", "**/*.js", false))
     // .concat(generateFileList("app/dataservice", "**/*.js", false))
     // .concat(generateFileList("app/model", "**/*.js", false))
     // .concat(generateFileList("app/reports", "**/*.js", false)),
                    baseUrl: "app/",
                    name: "",
                    paths: mixIn({}, requireConfig.paths, { "almond": "scripts/almond-custom.js" }),
                    optimize: 'none',
                    inlineText: true,
                    pragmas: {
                        build: true
                    },
                    stubModules: ['text'],
                    out: "dist/pm.js"
                }
            }
        }
```

The pm.js bundle gets downloaded and executed when anything in main-built requires it, right now its being done by the router in Durandal, but I'm pretty sure Durandal has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Please show the build config and how you trigger the loading of the `pm` bundle.

Answer (score 0):

This appears suspicious in your main file build:

```
paths: mixIn({}, requireConfig.paths, { "require": "scripts/require.js" }),
```

I'm not sure what the `mixIn` bit does as this is not stock RequireJS code, but you seem to want to include RequireJS in the build under the name `require`, which is definitely wrong. The [documentation says](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html):

> If you want to include require.js with the main.js source, you can use this kind of command:

```
node ../../r.js -o baseUrl=. paths.requireLib=../../require name=main include=requireLib out=main-built.js
```

> Since "require" is a reserved dependency name, you create a "requireLib" dependency and map it to the require.js file.

Comment: I'm not sure what the mixin does either, its something that I picked up from a Durandal task, but I don't think thats the issue, I can get requirejs included in the main-built file, but the problem is when I do that then the pm.js bundle will get a defined is undefined error when it loads.

Comment: Did you modify your build to do it like the documentation says to do it?

Comment: I've looked at the documentation a ton, not sure what I might be doing wrong

Comment: I meant that bit of the documentation I've pointed out in my answer.

Comment: I tried including require using a different module name and it had the same problem when the pm.js bundle loaded                       paths: mixIn({}, requireConfig.paths, { "requireLib": "../lib/require/require" }),
                    include: ["requireLib"],